# How would I find values in a file, but only on lines that don't start with #?

Tags: regex

I've got a document that looks something like this:

```
# Document ID 8934
# Last updated 2018-05-06
52 84 12 70 23 2 7 20 1 5
4 2 7 81 32 98 2 0 77 6
(..and so on..)
```

In other words, it starts off with a few comment lines, then the rest of the document is just a bunch of numbers separated by spaces.

I'm trying to write a regex that gets all digits on all lines that don't start with #, but I can't seem to get it.

I've read over answers such as

1. [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469913/regular-expressions-is-there-an-and-operator)
2. [Regex: Find a character anywhere in a document but only on lines that begin with a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698208/regex-find-a-character-anywhere-in-a-document-but-only-on-lines-that-begin-with)

   and pawed through sites such as http://regular-expressions.info, but I still can't get an expression that works (the best I can get is a lengthy version of `^[^#].*`

So how can I match digits (or text, or whatever) in a string, but only on lines that don't start with a certain character?

Comment: @rkta That just gets all lines that start with a hash. I want to combine that with something like `\d+` to get all digits on lines that don't start with a hash, as my question stated

Comment: which is the context of this? Probably, it would be a better idea to first check if the line begins with `#`, and then, use `\d+` on each line that doesn't begin with `#`

Comment: Question to ask yourself is : why use regex when the problem can be solved writing two lines of code?

Comment: @YassinHajaj part of this is because it's a challenge that'd test my regex knowledge. I've worked around it by using two lines, but now I'm curious about a one-regex answer.

Comment: @Grayda Oh alright that's fine

Comment: As easy as `(?<!^#.*?)\d+`, use with PyPi Python `regex` module, .NET regex, or in the latest versions of Chrome (JavaScript compatible with ECMAScript 2018 standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `^[^#].*` uses a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which matches  not a `#` from the start of the string `^` and after that matches any character zero or more times.
This would for example also match `t test`

What you might do is use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match a whole line `^#.*$` that starts with a # or capture in a group one or more digits `(\d+)`

Your digits are captured group 1. You could change the `(\d+)` to for example a character class `([\w+.]+)` to match more than only digits.

[`(?:^#.*$|(\d+))`](https://regex101.com/r/qqNHJm/1)

**Details**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^#.*$` Match from the start of the line `^` a # followed by any character zero or more times `.*` until the end of the string `$`
  - `|` Or
  - `(\d+)` capture one or more digits in a group
- `)` Close non capturing group

Comment: Nicely explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think a way simpler method would be to replace the lines with "" first with this regex:

```
^#.*
```

And then you can just match all the numbers with this:

```
-?\d+ (-? is for negative)
```

Comment: My code eventually used two lines as you suggested (though slightly different, using `^[^#]+` to catch all non-hashed lines then simply `\d+` for the digits), though I was interested to see if there was a "one liner", which there was via @the fourth bird's answer.